# Where is canonical reference that justifies os.pardir?

Tags: python, macos, standards, history, standards-compliance

Python standard library [includes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pardir) an `os.pardir` and supposedly identical `os.path.pardir`.

`os.py` states:

```
  - os.curdir is a string representing the current directory ('.' or ':')
  - os.pardir is a string representing the parent directory ('..' or '::')
```

and`macpath.py` has

```
curdir = ':'
pardir = '::'
sep = ':'
```

This seems to be enough justification for the inclusion of `os.pardir`.
I don't know about uses of pardir other than this.

As per Mac, however, I couldn't find a canonical reference of the history for Mac's support or requirement of `::` as parent directory notation.

As per other OSes, I don't know of any other OS that uses different pardir than `..`.

- Are there any other OSes where pardir should differ from `..`?
- Exactly which document (if any) has `::` specified as the path separator for older Mac <= 9?
- Which document specifies the backward compatibility of this notation with >= OSX?

Comment: [Here's a table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) showing different versions of the current/parent directory notation. It notes a few others besides '::' and '..'.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist very good. Too bad it has no references on them. :(

Comment: What kind of document are you looking for exactly?

Comment: As you've surmised, `macpath.py` refers to file paths for Classic Mac OS (<=9). In the early days of Mac OS X, Python provided wrappers for various Carbon APIs provided for compatibility with Classic Mac OS and `macpath.py` was useful for some of them.  However, Apple's decision to deprecate Carbon and not provide 64-bit versions have made those wrappers obsolete and deprecated.  While some can still be used on 32-bit builds of Python 2.x on current OS X versions, they have been removed in Python 3 and should be avoided, making `macpath.py` of very limited utility.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist like microsoft's [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) (albeit I'm not sure how much it is definitive), or POSIX' [parent directory definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_263). I think the wiki article refers to [foldoc](http://foldoc.org/pathname) too but it has no exotic OS delimiter :). I cannot find some docs for either classic Mac nor the other OS in that table, that specifically mentions `::`, or `^`, `<`, etc..